# perl, python, parallel processing,fork

Tags: python, perl

From Perl or python,Which language takes less overhead,less memory consumption and time while creating a process or parallel processing when sending or receiving a mail or messages? My client want to use any one technology perl or python?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: From one of your comments below, perhaps you should be using a job queue such as Gearman instead of worrying about which language fork()'s better.

Answer (score 5):

Which are you more familiar with? **Use that!** There would be minor differences in both for the conditions which you mention, but both would be slower than application written in compiled language such as C. But what you get is faster development time and ability to design using high level language features and libraries. So, the answer boils down to - use what are more familiar with.

Comment: I knew a basic things of the perl and my client is already using perl script but he is getting some bugs in the existing application(Using paraller::forkmanager) when sending messages.So, he is giving more strength on using python.

Comment: Just fix those bugs, instead of changing the language. Who knows you may encounter more unseen bugs in a new unfamiliar language to you?

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure the bottom line of creating a process is defined by your OS. Python and Perl will both go down to system calls pretty quickly, so I wouldn't worry about that any much.

If your application has any size at all and you are not a Perl expert, then I suggest using Python. Your brain will hurt a lot less.

At this stage of development, you could also try to **test** the various languages. Create a benchmark and some prototypes and get a feel for the languages.

Comment: I knew a basic things of the perl and my client is already using perl script but he is getting some bugs in the existing application(Using paraller::forkmanager) when sending messages.So, he is giving more strength on using python.we can't predict the no.os sizes to sending a messages or mails(Assuming nearly 500 million users)

Comment: @user634139: Sure, bugs in the code or bad design, blame it on the library or the language. Of course, it can't be the programmer's fault :-)

Comment: ...and I predict it will be an equally bad design in Python.